# How to write performance oriented map/reduce query in Erlang

Tags: erlang, riak, erlang-shell, erlang-escript

I am running a Erlang Map/Reduce on riak . In a bucket there are 57000 records where my map phase is getting the filtering records by 14 seconds.

```
-module(chatlogs).
-author("gopi").

%% API
-export([getListForUser/3]).


getListForUser(Obj,_kd,Chat_id) ->
case catch mochijson2:decode(hd(riak_object:get_values(Obj))) of
{struct, Data} ->
     Event_list = [<<"INTRO_MSG">>, <<"QUESTION">>, <<"VALID_ANSWER">>,  <<"NEW_MSG">>],
    case proplists:get_value(<<"chat_id">>,Data) == Chat_id  of
    true ->
            case lists:member(proplists:get_value(<<"Event-Name">>,Data),Event_list) of
                    true->
                            [Data];
                    false->
                            []
            end;
    false ->
            []
    end;
_ ->
   []
end.
```

is there any better way to reduce and improve the code performance

Comment: Did you try to profile your code? Maybe that shows us where the bottlenecks are. For example if json decoding is too slow you can try another json parser.

Comment: If you are using Bitcask, this is going to fold over _all_ keys in _every_ bucket, not just the 57,000 records in the bucket you want to consider.  If you are using LevelDB, you could use a 2I query on the $bucket index as input to the map for a bit of a performance boost.

Comment: I agree with @P_A the first thing to do is to measure so you know where the time goes. Without that you cannot do any serious attempts at improving the performance

Comment: I am using Bitcask, i am using this python-riak client. 
so i am giving like query = client.add(bucket_name)
It will only search the bucket what i have given , am i right??
if so how to do

Comment: First do just the `riak_object:get_values(Obj)` alone and see how long time that takes. If that is where the time is going then it might be as @Joe says. If not then it is the JSON parsing and as @P_A says try another JSON decoder. Before you measure you don't know.

Comment: Btw will the `riak_object:get_values(Obj)` return all the values?

Comment: yes it is giving the total values i have checked it @ rvirding

Comment: I am using Bitcask , it is taking time for riak_object:get_values(obj) @joe

Comment: @GopiKrishna yes, in Riak, buckets and keys are just namespaced pointers to data. If you don't use 2i to reduce the number of keys you're searching, you will always search *all* of the keys in Riak. That'll be extremely slow.

Comment: but 2i is only used for LevelDB and Memory Backends i am using Bitcask @ Srdjan Pejic

Comment: @GopiKrishna then switch your backend. You're asking how to make the query more performant, we give you solutions and you're countering with the desire not to execute those solutions. Fact of the matter is, certain backends support certain things and you need to switch if you want performance.